# PHP-PDO-Mysql: Can't execute two requests in the same page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, request

I'm moving a php application to a new web server.
 In the origin server, the following code is working, but it is not in the new server.

```
$request=$connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM access_control ");
$request->execute(); 

$request2=$connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tplmail ");
$request2->execute();`
```

The first request always works. I tried to reverse the two requests, but the script always stop at the second `execute`. In the others scripts, there is the same problem, I can't do two `execute`s in the same page.

Comment: Does it give you any error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem #1 is lack of error reporting. Without seeing an error message you will be unable to do anything

To be able to see database errors, one have to set [PDO errmode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to exceptions. Exceptions are better than regular errors in many ways: they always contains a stack trace, they can be caught using try..catch or handled using dedicated error handler. And even unhandled, they act as regular PHP errors providing all the important information, following site-wide error reporting settings.

Note that setting this mode as a connection option will let PDO throw exceptions on connection errors too, which is very important.
So, here is an example for creating a PDO connection right way:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    // other options 
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Connecting this way, you will be always notified of all database errors, occurred during query execution. Note that you have to be able to see PHP errors in general. On a live site you have to peek into error logs, so, settings have to be

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

while on a local development server it's ok to make errors on screen:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and of course you should never ever use error suppression operator (`@`) in front of your PDO statements.

Also, due to many bad examples telling you to wrap every PDO statement into `try..catch` block, I have to make a distinct note:

> **DO NOT use try..catch operator just to echo an error message.** Uncaught exception is already excellent for this purpose, as it will act just the same way as other PHP errors - so, you can define the behavior using site-wide settings - so, **you will have your error message without this useless code.** *While unconditionally echoed error message may reveal some sensitive information to a potential attacker, yet confuse a honest visitor.*
>
> - A [custom exception handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) could be added later, but not required. Especially for new users, it is recommended to use unhandled exceptions, as they are extremely informative, helpful and secure.
> - Use `try..catch` only if you are going to handle the error itself - say, to rollback a transaction.

Your problem #2 is a [**buffering state**](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) which prevent second query from execution.

Adding

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => TRUE,
```

to the init array should solve the problem

Or you can just fetch all the data from the first query before firing the second

Comment: Thank you for your help. I use a a "try catch" to declare my PDO but I will change that. I added "PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true", it's not working with "false" but with true it's working well now.

Comment: Thanks, it was stupid typo of me, I mindlessly copy-pasted the command from manual page. Fixed now.